# Facebook Like button showing 0

Tags: facebook

does anyone know why when liking this link the button automatically refreshes to 0?

http://notable.ca/toronto/event-detail/Ad-Clubs-Summer-Party/

I think i am using the correct FB code and it seems to work fine on all other articles ...

Thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks like the url of your that isnt properly url encoded in the facebook url variable.

Answer (score 1):

try making sure the URL you are using is encoded properly - I just tried it via facebook developer page and worked fine - and also showed my like from the page too.

your code shows this

`http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
href=http://notable.ca/toronto/Ad%20Clubs%20Summer%20Party`

try

`http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://notable.ca/toronto/Ad-Clubs-Summer-Party`

Comment: I also get this error if it means anything to you when trying to like via your page The page at http://notable.ca/search.php?s= could not be reached.

Comment: hi did this sort out your problem? if so maybe you should mark a correct answer? thanks